# Win 8, Win 8.1 + IE 11 Fixed Positioning Bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm dealing with wierd behavior of IE 11 on Windows 8 and Windows 8.1. I'm fixing position of element inside fixed positioned element. And it's rendering weird. It's in right place when I inspect it with dev tools, but visually its completly in different place. I found out that if I temporarily disable position rule of parent element and then enable it again, the child element renders correctly after that. IE 11 on Win 7 doesn't have this problem.

HTML:

```
<body style="" class="modal-open">

    <div class="container">
        <div id="bg-overlay" class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">


<div id="photo-modal" class="modal fade in" style="display: block;" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"><img src="d4wbqxn.jpg" width="1100" height="600" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="padding-bottom: 104px;">
                <div id="comments" class="clearfix"><div class="comment guest" style="">

        <img src="avatar50x50.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar img-circle">

        <a href="#" class="user" data-id="5">Test1</a>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="well well-sm">Cool</div>
        </div>
        <small>01/02/2014 20:01</small>
    </div><div class="comment owner" style="">

        <img src="50x50.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar img-circle">

        <a href="#" class="user" data-id="6">Owner</a>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="well well-sm">Thanks</div>
        </div>
        <small>01/02/2014 20:09</small>
    </div><div class="comment owner" style="">

        <img src="50x50.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar img-circle">

        <a href="#" class="user" data-id="7">Owner</a>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="well well-sm">Thanks</div>
        </div>
        <small>01/03/2014 11:38</small>
    </div><div class="comment owner" style="">

        <img src="50x50.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar img-circle">

        <a href="#" class="user" data-id="8">Owner</a>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="well well-sm">Thanks</div>
        </div>
        <small>01/03/2014 12:13</small>
    </div><div class="comment owner" style="">

        <img src="50x50.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar img-circle">

        <a href="#" class="user" data-id="9">Owner</a>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="well well-sm">Thanks</div>
        </div>
        <small>01/03/2014 12:14</small>
    </div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form role="form" class="text-center" style="width: 1100px; left: 401.5px; margin-bottom: 0px; visibility: visible;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" style="height: 35px; overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal;" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add">Add</button>
    </form>

</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div></body>
```

CSS:

```
.btn {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.btn-default {
  border-color: #fff;
}
.btn-default:hover, .btn-default:focus {
  background-color: #ecf9fe;
  border-color: #ecf9fe;
}

.btn-danger {
  background-color: #facc16;
  border-color: #facc16;
  color: #313131;
}
.btn-danger:hover, .btn-danger:focus {
  background-color: #f0c105;
  border-color: #dcb104;
  color: #242424;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #b1e6fb;
  border: none;
}

.modal-header {
  background-color: #c5ecfc;
  border: 1px solid #c5ecfc;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.modal-title {
  font-family: GardensC, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal-footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #9ee0fa;
  border: 1px solid #9ee0fa;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
}
.modal-footer .btn-primary {
  color: #313131;
  background-color: #51c7f6;
  border-color: #51c7f6;
}
.modal-footer .btn-primary:hover, .modal-footer .btn-primary:focus {
  color: #242424;
  background-color: #3dc1f5;
  border-color: #3dc1f5;
}

#error-message .modal-content {
  background-color: #2ab9f3;
  padding: 20px;
}
#error-message p {
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #b1e6fb;
}

#move-photo-modal .modal-header {
  background-color: #b1e6fb;
  border: 1px solid #b1e6fb;
}
#move-photo-modal .album {
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1fa2f0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#move-photo-modal .album .text {
  font-family: GardensC, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #b1e6fb;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(2) {
  background: #a6e1fa;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(3) {
  background: #9cdcf9;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(4) {
  background: #91d7f8;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(5) {
  background: #87d2f7;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(6) {
  background: #7ccdf7;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(7) {
  background: #72c8f6;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(8) {
  background: #68c4f5;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(9) {
  background: #5dbff4;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(10) {
  background: #53baf3;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(11) {
  background: #48b5f3;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(12) {
  background: #3eb0f2;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(13) {
  background: #33abf1;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(14) {
  background: #29a6f0;
}
#move-photo-modal .modal-footer {
  margin-top: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: auto;
}

.comment {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}
.comment small {
  display: block;
  font-size: 80%;
}
.comment .user {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0d4ca6;
}
.comment .well {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.comment .avatar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.comment.guest {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
.comment.guest small {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.comment.guest .user {
  margin-left: 55px;
}
.comment.guest .well {
  border-color: #facc16;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  float: left;
}
.comment.owner {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
.comment.owner small {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.comment.owner .user {
  margin-right: 55px;
}
.comment.owner .well {
  border-color: #0d4ca6;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  float: right;
}
.comment.owner .avatar {
  right: 0;
}

#move-photo-modal .modal-header {
  background-color: #b1e6fb;
  border: 1px solid #b1e6fb;
}
#move-photo-modal .album {
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1fa2f0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#move-photo-modal .album .text {
  font-family: GardensC, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #b1e6fb;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(2) {
  background: #a6e1fa;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(3) {
  background: #9cdcf9;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(4) {
  background: #91d7f8;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(5) {
  background: #87d2f7;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(6) {
  background: #7ccdf7;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(7) {
  background: #72c8f6;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(8) {
  background: #68c4f5;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(9) {
  background: #5dbff4;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(10) {
  background: #53baf3;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(11) {
  background: #48b5f3;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(12) {
  background: #3eb0f2;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(13) {
  background: #33abf1;
}
#move-photo-modal .album:nth-child(14) {
  background: #29a6f0;
}
#move-photo-modal .modal-footer {
  margin-top: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: auto;
}

#photo-modal form {
  background-color: #9ee0fa;
  border: 1px solid #9ee0fa;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1060;
}
#photo-modal .modal-header {
  min-height: 45px;
}
#photo-modal .modal-header .close {
  margin-top: -8px;
  font-size: 31px;
}
#photo-modal .modal-body p {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #photo-modal .modal-dialog, #photo-modal form {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
  }
}

.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #2ab9f3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(42, 185, 243, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(42, 185, 243, 0.6);
}
```

JS:

```
$.fn.ready(function () {
    OnShown();
    $('#photo-modal').scroll(OnScroll);
    $(window).resize(OnScroll);
});

function OnShown() {
    var $modal = $('#photo-modal');
    $modal.find('.modal-footer').css('padding-bottom', $modal.find('form').height() + 20);
    OnScroll();
}

function OnScroll() {
    var $modal = $('#photo-modal');
    var $dialog = $modal.find('.modal-dialog');
    var $footer = $modal.find('.modal-footer');
    var $form = $modal.find('form');
    $form.width($dialog.width() - 42)
        .css({
            'left': $dialog.offset().left
        });

    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    var elTop = $modal.offset().top;
    var footerTop = $footer.offset().top;

    var dialogMB = parseInt($dialog.css('margin-bottom'));
    if ($modal.scrollTop() + wHeight >= $dialog.outerHeight(true) - dialogMB) {
        $form.css('margin-bottom', dialogMB);
    } else {
        $form.css('margin-bottom', 0);
    }

    if (footerTop - elTop + $form.outerHeight(true) < wHeight) {
        $form.css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
        $form.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
}
```

I created fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SovietSam/TmmAV/

If you'll be lucky to not view the problem, try to resize the result pane (in some dimensions sometimes it renders correctly).

Comment: The problem is facing also in desktop version of IE11, or maybe you have tried only in "modern UI" version of IE? Beacuse they are formerly two different program, with different engine (while obviously common in many places)

Comment: Tried only in desktop version, not in new "metro" (or how it called now) version.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that but I will not help you if you not format your code readable...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a background color/image and an element is fixed on top of it, you have to remove the *backface* of that *element* to avoid repainting issues. Add these properties and remove visibility.

**CSS**:

```
#photo-modal form {
  ...
  display: none;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

**JS**:

```
if (footerTop - elTop + $form.outerHeight(true) < wHeight)
  $form.css('display', 'block');
else
  $form.css('display', 'none');
```

Why **display** instead of **visibility**, because *visibility* just hides the context, this doesn't change its interaction with other elements.